# Conway Problem, Space of Analytic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** *Let $f, f_1, f_2, . . .$ be elements of $H(G)$ and show that $f_n\longrightarrow f$ iff for each closed rectifiable curve $\gamma$ in $G$, $f_n(z)\longrightarrow f (z)$ uniformly for z in $\{\gamma\}$.*

Why is not this a trivial matter? I still do not really understand what the question asks, since if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on every $G$, should not $f_n$ converge to $f$ on the curves contained in $G$?

Please explain to me, and if possible give me a choice of how to solve.

Thank you!

Comment: One direction is indeed trivial. The other direction requires at least some thought.

Comment: The implication => is trivial correct? The back that is not.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is correct if $f_n \to f$ is understood as *locally uniform*
convergence. I would suggest to show that the following statements 
are equivalent:

1. $f_n \to f$ uniformly on each compact subset $K \subset G$.
2. $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\{\gamma\}$ for each closed rectifiable
   curve $\gamma $ in $G$.
3. $f_n \to f$ uniformly on the boundary of every closed disk
   which is completely contained in $G$.
4. Each point $z \in G$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that  $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $U$.

by proving $(1) \Rightarrow (2) \Rightarrow (3) \Rightarrow (4) \Rightarrow (1) $.

Some of the implications are trivial.
For $(3) \Rightarrow (4)$ you can use Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: In the case, I take the curve $\gamma$ as being the edge of the closing disk contained in $G$.

Comment: @LucianoGauss: For $(2) \to (3)$, yes.

Comment: @LucianoGauss: Does this help? Please let me know if you need more information!